# ALSA - Change mic gain in c code using alsa api (linux)

Tags: linux, alsa

I'm trying to mute the mic from inside my application using the alsa api on a linux box.
I'm using the following code for changing the volume with volume=0:

```
long min, max;
snd_mixer_t *handle;
snd_mixer_selem_id_t *sid;
const char *card = "default";
const char *selem_name = "Capture";
snd_mixer_open(&handle, 0);
snd_mixer_attach(handle, card);
snd_mixer_selem_register(handle, NULL, NULL);
snd_mixer_load(handle);
snd_mixer_selem_id_alloca(&sid);
snd_mixer_selem_id_set_index(sid, 0);
snd_mixer_selem_id_set_name(sid, selem_name);
snd_mixer_elem_t* elem = snd_mixer_find_selem(handle, sid);
snd_mixer_selem_get_capture_volume_range(elem, &min, &max);
snd_mixer_selem_set_capture_volume_all(elem, volume * max / 100);
snd_mixer_close(handle);
```

This works and capture volume is reduced to zero in alsamixer.
But I also want to change the mic gain to 0dB using the api and I don't seem to figure out how to achieve this...

Any ideas?

Thanks

Edit: Thanks CL. it worked. Can't paste my code for 7 more hours though.

Answer (score 2):

This code:

```c
const char *selem_name = "Capture";
snd_mixer_selem_id_set_index(sid, 0);
snd_mixer_selem_id_set_name(sid, selem_name);
```

selects the first control named "`Capture`".

Change the name to whatever the control for the mic gain happens to be on your machine.

If that control's type is not number but enumerated, you have to use `snd_mixer_selem_set_enum_item()` to change its value.

Comment: I am recording audio using snd_pcm_t handle. I want to enable and disable mic. Also, I want to set gain and get current gain. Can you please help ?